# Alamofire keeps getting cancelled

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

```
  @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder,     UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
var manager1: SessionManager?
var manager2: SessionManager?
let commons:Commons = Commons()
var selected = 0
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}    
func uploade()
{
    if(selected == 0)
    {
        let realm = try! Realm()            
        let uploadAuditInfo = realm.objects(UploadAudit.self)
        var uploadAudit =  [UploadAudit]()            
        let uploadDistInfo = realm.objects(UploadData.self)
        var uploadDist =  [UploadData]()            
        for i in 0 ..< uploadAuditInfo.count {
            if let result = uploadAuditInfo[i] as? UploadAudit {
                uploadAudit.append(result)
            }
        }            
        for i in 0 ..< uploadDistInfo.count {
            if let result = uploadDistInfo[i] as? UploadData {
                uploadDist.append(result)
            }
        }   
        if(uploadAudit.count > 0)
        {               
            selected = 1
            let upload = uploadAudit[0]
            let fileNameToDelete = upload.fileName
            var filePath = ""
            let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)                
            if dirs.count > 0 {
                let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
                filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)           
            } else {               
                return
            }    
            let lang = self.commons.getLanguage()
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath)
            {
                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
                let ids = upload.id
                let params  = upload.params
                let name1 = upload.fileName
                let url = self.commons.getUrl()
                let vas1 = lang+params
                let vas2 = url+"rest/secure/"+String(ids)+"/submit?language="
                let vas = vas2+vas1            
                print("upload audit111")
                uploadFile(fileName: name1, mimeType:"application/octed-stream", image: image!, url:vas, id: ids)
            }
            else
            {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(upload)
                }
                selected = 0
                self.uploade()
            }
        }
        else if(uploadDist.count > 0)
        {
            selected = 1
            let upload = uploadDist[0]
            let fileNameToDelete = upload.fileName
            var filePath = ""
            let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)                
            if dirs.count > 0 {
                let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
                filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)   
            } else {                   
                return
            }
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath)
            {
                let lang = self.commons.getLanguage()
                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
                let ids = upload.id
                let params  = upload.params
                let name1 = upload.fileName  
                let url = self.commons.getUrl()
                let vas1 = lang+params
                let vas2 = url+"rest/secure/another/"+String(ids)+"/submit?language="
                let vas = vas2+vas1
                print("upload dist111")
                uploadFileDist(fileName: name1, mimeType:"application/octed-stream", image: image!, url:vas, id: ids)
            }
            else
            {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(upload)
                }
                selected = 0
                self.uploade()
            }
        }
        else
        {      
        }}
    else
    {            
    }
}
func uploadFileDist(fileName: String, mimeType: String, image: UIImage, url: String, id: Int )
{
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let currentLevelKey = "sessionId"
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: currentLevelKey) == nil {            
    } else {
        let name = preferences.string(forKey: currentLevelKey)
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let sessionName = "JSESSIONID="+name!
            // get headers
            let headers = self.commons.getHeader(cookie: sessionName)
            // get language                
            // get configuration
            let configuration = self.commons.getConfiguration(timeout: 600)
            self.manager2 = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
            // get base url                
            let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)                
            let uuid = UUID().uuidString
            let uuid2 = UUID().uuidString
            let nameOfImage = "profile-"+uuid+"--"+uuid2                
            print("dist upload")
            self.manager2!.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in                    
                MultipartFormData.append(image_data!, withName: "uploadFile", fileName: nameOfImage+".jpeg", mimeType: mimeType)
            }, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
                //self.manager1!.session.invalidateAndCancel()
                 print("dist result")
                switch result {                    
                case .success( let upload , _, _):
                    upload.responseObject(keyPath: ""){ (response: DataResponse<User>) in
                        let realm = try! Realm()
                        let ps = "id == "+String(id)
                        let datas = realm.objects(UploadData.self).filter(ps)
                        let datas2 = realm.objects(DistRealM.self).filter(ps)
                        try! realm.write {
                            realm.delete(datas)
                            realm.delete(datas2)
                        }
                        self.selected = 0
                        self.uploade()
                    }                      
               case .failure( _):
                    self.selected = 0
                }                   
            })
        }
    }
}
 func uploadFile(fileName: String, mimeType: String, image: UIImage, url: String, id: Int )
{
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let currentLevelKey = "sessionId"
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: currentLevelKey) == nil {            
    } else {
        let name = preferences.string(forKey: currentLevelKey)
        DispatchQueue.global().async {                
            // set session cookie
            let sessionName = "JSESSIONID="+name!
            // get headers
            let headers = self.commons.getHeader(cookie: sessionName)
            // get language                
            // get configuration
            let configuration = self.commons.getConfiguration(timeout: 600)
            self.manager2 = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
            // get base url
             print(" audit upload ")
            let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)
            let uuid = UUID().uuidString
            let uuid2 = UUID().uuidString
            let nameOfImage = "profile-"+uuid+"--"+uuid2
            self.manager2!.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in                    
                MultipartFormData.append(image_data!, withName: "uploadFile", fileName: nameOfImage+".jpeg", mimeType: mimeType)
            }, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
                // self.manager1!.session.invalidateAndCancel()
                 print("audit result")
                switch result {                        
                case .success( let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseObject(keyPath: ""){ (response: DataResponse<User>) in
                        debugPrint(response)
                        let realm = try! Realm()
                        let ps = "id == "+String(id)
                        let datas = realm.objects(UploadAudit.self).filter(ps)
                        let datas2 = realm.objects(AuditRealM.self).filter(ps)
                        try! realm.write {
                            realm.delete(datas)
                            realm.delete(datas2)
                        }
                        self.selected = 0
                        self.uploade()
                    }                        
                case .failure( _):
                    self.selected = 0
                }                    
            })
        }
    }}}
```

I am doing this in swift 3 using alamofire lirbary, this same call works elsewhere perfectly. However on here, i keep getting Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=

Why does my url call keeps getting cancelled for no reason?the same call works in elsewhere perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your not saying anything about App Transport Security Settings, so I give it a try:

What might happening is that App Transport Security is blocking your requests.

> App Transport Security (ATS), introduced in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11, improves user security and privacy by requiring apps to use secure network connections over HTTPS.
>
> Your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.

To make an exception  in info.plist file is easy.
Add a `NSAppTransportSecurity` key and add a dictionary of `NSExceptionDomains` under. Then add your domains as keys and you don't need to write anything in the string value. Also add a `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to allow insecure connections

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>unsecuredomain.com</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>sub.unsecure.co.uk</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```